# Print HTML in angular 9

Tags: angular, printing, angular-material, angular8

I have a table created using angular material, where each row has a print button.
On click of "Print" button, I need to fetch details of the record and open a print window for it.

The details will be in another component with different layout.

Can anyone guide me on it.

Comment: Okay.. Where is the code that you have tried??

Comment: I have used https://stackblitz.com/github/IdanCo/angular-print-service, but my API is invoked when I hit the cancel button of print popup